# How many table we can join in db2?

Tags: sql, performance, join, db2

I need to join with many table (36 table) on db2, because I need many columns from table which data it show in rows and must transpose it.

I need to know if I join more table in case how does effect with db?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is dependent upon which platform you are using (IBM i, z/OS, or LUW) and which version.

[Limits in DB2 10 for z/OS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_limits.htm)

> Maximum number of base tables in a view, SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, MERGE, or DELETE = 225
>
> Maximum number of tables in a FROM clause =   225 or fewer, depending on the complexity of the statement
>
> Maximum number of subqueries in a statement = 224

[Limits in DB2 for i 7.1](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzlimtabs.htm)

> Maximum number of tables referenced in a view or materialized query table = 256 <sup>(See note 8)</sup>
>
> Maximum number of tables referenced in an SQL statement = 1000 <sup>(see note 8)</sup>
>
> (8):  The maximum number of members (and partitions) referenced is also 1000. In DELETE and UPDATE statements the maximum number is 256.

[Limits in DB2 10.1 LUW](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0001029.html)

> Maximum number of tables referenced in an SQL statement or a view = (dependent on storage)

Comment: Thank you, If I separate join such as join table abc=table1, join def=table2, join ijk =table3 and the last I join table1,2,3 Is is better than I join table abcdefijk at the same time?

Comment: Thank you, If I separate join such as join table abc=table1, join def=table2, join ijk =table3 and the last I join table1,2,3 Is is better than I join table abcdefijk at the same time?

Comment: I'm not quite sure *exactly* what you are asking, however (at least on DB2 for i) it is *often* better to join things in one query, and let the optimizer sort out the best way to handle things.  YMMV on other platforms, and many situations are different.  You might want to post a more detailed question separately, either here, or on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

DB2 can reference 1,000 tables in a single statement (according to [IBM documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzlimtabs.htm)).

All databases that I know of would support 36.